# How to search the data based on the keyin alphabets instead of wild search in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a dropdown where in i have 100 of dropdown values, so based on key input values i am able to search the values but these values are searching based on wild search, i want the dropdown to show me the values of what alphabets i enter first.

HTML:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left m-b10 m-t10">
    <label class="lbl_manifes pull-left col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 text-sm-left no-padd">Manifestation
      <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 pull-left no-padd w-71">
      <input type='text' (keyup)="searchDropDown(175, src13.value)" #src13 formControlName="Manifestation" [(ngModel)]="selectedManifestation" placeholder="Please keyin (eg:Ac)"
      />
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <div *ngIf="allergyDropDown && allergyDropDown?.manifestation && IsHidden" class="emr-dropdown">
        <ul *ngFor="let manifestationType of allergyDropDown?.manifestation" (click)="getValue(manifestationType)" class="p-l10 m-b0 brd-b">
          <li>
            {{manifestationType.Description}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

TS:

```
  public getValue(item) {
    this.IsHidden = false;
    if (item.CategoryId == 175) {
      this.selectedManifestation = item.Description;
    }
  }

  public searchDropDown(Id, desc) {
      let params = { Id, desc: desc }
      this.emrService.getDropDown(params)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.IsHidden = true;
          this.initializeAllDropDown(res.Body.Data)
        })
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but your search results seem to be coming from the emrService.getDropDown() method - which you didn't include in your question...

Comment: @Hoff ya i am getting dropdowns from emrService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have updated your function to show only nearest closet search result, I have filter from item.desc you can write actual column name from which you want to filter, this will help you resolve your search issue.
Update your searchDropdown function as below,

```
public searchDropDown(Id, desc, index) {
    let params = { Id: Id, desc: desc }
    this.emrService.getDropDown(params)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.IsHidden = true;
        this.contactIndex = index;
        var data = res.Body.Data.filter(item => item.desc.toLowerCase().indexOf(desc.toLowerCase())==0);
        this.initializeAllDropDown(data)
      })
  }
```